# Updating nested list results in an object instead of array

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to do an update of a field from a list nested in another list with this query:

```
db.getCollection('TABLENAME').update({
    "_id": ObjectId("5e5f8007bfe44c1628290ca9")
}, {
    "$set": {
        "outerList.0.innerList.0.code": "c8"
    }
})
```

The problem appears when the `innerList=null`. In this case innerList is created but instead of array it is an object:

```
{
    outerList: [
        {
            innerList: {
                "0": {
                    code: 'c8'
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What to do to ensure that innerList will always be an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `push` instead of `set`. The solution is shown below:

```
> db.test2.insert({"_id":ObjectId("5e5fa4755d801f5c672addbb"),"outerList": []})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test2.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e5fa4755d801f5c672addbb"), "outerList" : [ ] }
> db.test2.update({"_id": ObjectId("5e5fa4755d801f5c672addbb")}, {"$push": {"outerList.0.innerlist":{"0":"c8"}}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
> db.test2.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e5fa4755d801f5c672addbb"), "outerList" : [ { "innerlist" : [ { "0" : "c8" } ] } ] }
```

As can be seen, `innerlist` is an array.

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: Yes, it seems that it initialize the innerList as array if it's null.